# How analyze reliability of position of new point based on point data

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, distance, crowdsourcing, machine-learning

I am working on filter for biogeographical data. It is based on citizen science principle. People put new point data to database and I want add information about "reliability" or probability (maybe expressed by score) of added point. Please look on the picture for better understanding.

[image: I need predict probability or score that green point is placed good based on old data]

In the picture it is visualize like zones with score, but it is only one way how to get something like this. Other maybe should be use distance between points. I don't know what I should find and where I should start finding.

What should I search on the internet and books when I need explore more ways how predict probability (or some type of score) to express new added point is placed good (It can be placed there)?

I need handle it in python but for a start it is probably good idea try it in QGIS or ArcGIS, or other software.

**EDIT**

So I tried something like this:

[image]

It looks it works but, what do you think. Is it good approach with appropriate formula?

Then I thought about Mean of Inverse distance. What do you think about this approach?

Should I define some buffer or distance where I will take points into account for RMSE?

Comment: Look into the Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) which is a de facto standard in this type of assessment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply and sorry for my late answer. I was too busy and forgot for this my question. What do you think about edited question please? You can rewrite your comment to answer and I will mark it as good.